Pandas rank to Excel rank
I have a sample data from which i am calculating the rank
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"value": [500,500,200,101,100,72,63,55,50,30,30,20,1]})

print(df)

print(df["value"].rank())

print(df["value"].rank(pct=True))

The results are as follows
    value  rank      perc
0     500  12.5  0.961538
1     500  12.5  0.961538
2     200  11.0  0.846154
3     101  10.0  0.769231
4     100   9.0  0.692308
5      72   8.0  0.615385
6      63   7.0  0.538462
7      55   6.0  0.461538
8      50   5.0  0.384615
9      30   3.5  0.269231
10     30   3.5  0.269231
11     20   2.0  0.153846
12      1   1.0  0.076923

I want to calculate the rank and perc columns in excel
if i try to apply this formula =RANK.AVG(A1,$A$1:$A$13,0), i am getting different ranking numbers
1.5
1.5
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10.5
10.5
12
13

Can someone help me with the excel formula. I want to reproduce the same results as in the dataframe.
What changes i have to do in the EXCEL formula to achieve the values shown above in the dataframe?

Just substract ROW([YOUR_RANGE]) and then add 1, so It should looks like =RANK.AVG(A1,$A$1:$A$13,0) - ROW($A$1:$A$13) + 1

Change the 0 to a 1: https://i.sstatic.net/fnZOFC6t.png

Thanks . Any idea what formula for achieving perc column values ?

Your Excel RANK is just ranking in the wrong order. Change the order (from descending to ascending) and it will return the same values.

Explanation about excel :
The formula =RANK.AVG(A1, $A$1:$A$13, 0) in Excel calculates the rank in descending order (largest to smallest), whereas pandas ranks in ascending order (smallest to largest) by default.
To reproduce the pandas behavior, you need to reverse the ranking order. This can be done by using the formula:
=RANK.AVG(A1, $A$1:$A$13, 1)



Here, the 1 parameter specifies ascending order, matching the default behavior of pandas.

Now, for the percentile  :
To calculate the percentage rank (similar to the rank(pct=True) in pandas), you can use the PERCENTRANK.INC function in Excel:
Percentile Rank Formula in Excel:
=PERCENTRANK.INC($A$1:$A$13, A1)

